# Custom metric for vertx

Tags: vert.x, micrometer

I am using Vertx micrometer (with Prometheus option) and I would like to ask if it's possible to add a custom metric.

I would like to keep track of a number of users with a specific property so I need to call a service (via event bus) to get this number. Finally, I want to include this number in the metrics collected by Prometheus.

Thank you

Michael

Comment: Take a look at https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-micrometer-metrics/java/#_user_defined_metrics

Comment: Thanks, I already had a look at this but I did not find the way to fit it in my scenario. I found that I could use gauge meter (that gets a current value from a supplier) but I don't know how to compute my value from the database and pass it to the meter with rxJava.

Comment: You could create the gauge and then periodically update its value. http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementingdecrementing_a_gauge